# how to remove file from folder and subfolder single command linux

Tags: linux, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-volume, superuser

How to delete file from folder and subfolder currently using below command for delete logs but i want delete logs file in folder and subfolder in Linux .

currently i am doing enter every folder and delete log for specific year.
is there any command for delete same file from folder and subfolder in linux

```
volumes/abc/http.log2019-07-09
volumes/cdf/http.log2019-07-09
```

i want single command for delete files all folders in Linux

Currently using below command for delete file

```
sudo rm http.log2019*
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use "find" command with "delete" option. This will remove files with specified name in current directory and sub directories.

```
find . -name "http.log2019*" -delete
```

Comment: sudo find . -name "http.log2019*" -type f –delete    (Delete file from folder and subfolder)

Comment: what if find is not available in my shell?

bash-5.1$ find
bash: find: command not found

Comment: @star can you check command "which find" ? or can you see your find script inside  /usr/bin?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` command to list all the files matching a pattern and then iterate over the list to delete each of the files individually.

```
find <directory_path> -regex '.*http.log2019[^/]*'
```

This returns files within the mentioned directory and its subdirectories along with their relative paths. Now you can use `rm` command over the list to delete all of them. Assuming that your directory path is `/Volume/`, you can do as following-

```
for file_path in `find /Volume/ -regex '.*http.log2019[^/]*'`; do sudo rm $file_path; done
```

If you also want to delete the directories matching that pattern within the current directory and its subdirectories, then include option `-r` with `rm`.